# Programmatically repaint form

Tags: excel, vba

I have an programmatically created a userform with code

```
Sub RedibujaFormProgressBar()
    debug.print "Here" 'Only For control
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

From a code module, I try to call it with

```
Call m_FormProgressBar.RedibujaFormProgressBar
```

As result, inmediate window shows "Here", but when trying to repaint, i receive error 13 (Type MisMatch)

I need to repaint the form in order to show progress. Any idea?

Comment: When you get the error, where does the code stop?

Comment: Hello. Thenks for your quick answerIn me. Repaint

Comment: Sorry: the code stop in me. Repaint

Comment: instead of `Me` use the name of the Userform, e.g. `Userform1.Repaint`

Comment: Run this `RedibujaFormProgressBar` step by step using F8 and see in which line the error occurs then. Actually it is very unlikely that the  `Me.Repaint` can throw a "Type Mismatch" error itself.

Comment: `Me` can be used only inside `Forms` or `Objects` (sheets, user forms) assigned to events (change, initialize, activate etc.), so use direct name of userform, e.g. `Userform1.Repaint` as specified by @MarcoGetrost